# Hide Sharepoint 2016 list fields based on User permissions

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have sharepoint 2016 List form . It have a field that we have to hide from users based on SharePoint Groups.
 So far my reaserch have shown that writing a javascript file that will help doing that. It haven't worked. I added the code on NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx , NewForm.aspx etc
I have that same thing in SP 2010 but it seems 2016 Sharepoint is designed in different way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, depends what your constraints are. The following freeware github code solution works great for me on SharePoint 2016 on prem in new, display and edit forms for a custom list. It was easy to implement and worked first time no issue:

- https://davidlozzi.com/2014/01/14/sharepoint-2013-script-hide-or-disable-your-fields/

You need only include jQuery, the author's js file and then this fragment of js in your list forms

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    Lozzi.Fields.hideWithAllowance("Start Date", ["Project Managers"]);
    Lozzi.Fields.hide("% Complete");
    Lozzi.Fields.show("Title");
  },"sp.js");
});
```

There are several other functions in the library, to disable and disable with permissions.

I went one step further and used CSS to hide the fields so even if the js didn't run the fields would still be hidden:

```
table .ms-formtable > tbody > tr:not(#idAttachmentsRow) 
{
  display:none;
}
```

But then you need to `.show()` any fields that aren't restricted by permissions or make the CSS selector more precise which is hard since SharePoint buries the field name in an inner HTML comment rather than putting it in an attribute of the row. But that is separate issue.